# Check if a double = 1/3

Tags: java, math

I have made a function that converts a `double` to a simplified fraction in Java:

```
public static int gcm(int a, int b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcm(b, a % b);
}
public static String toFraction(double d) {
    int decimals = String.valueOf(d).split("\\.")[1].length();
    int mult = (int) Math.pow(10, decimals);
    int numerator = (int) (d * mult);
    int denominator = mult;
    // now simplify
    int gcm = gcm(numerator, denominator);
    numerator /= gcm;
    denominator /= gcm;
    return numerator + "/" + denominator;
}
```

It works, except for the fact that if I use `toFraction(1.0/3)`, this will, understandably, return `"715827882/2147483647"`. How may I fix this to return `"1/3"`?

Comment: @MickMnemonic How would BigDecimal represent 1/3 without representation error?

Comment: I don't see how this approach will work. a double is not a decimal, nor would it help if it was. Are you open to other solutions?

Comment: Agreed. The OP should be using BigDecimal or something similar.

Comment: It might help to look at the source of Python's [`fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/fractions.py#l206), which performs a task highly related to your problem.

Comment: Peter is correct, not all rational numbers can be modeled with `BigDecimal`. However, Apache Commons Math has classes for modeling [fractions](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/fraction.html), which are good for this purpose.

Comment: Look for "continued fraction expansion". The convergents make good rational approximations and usually provide good markers that let you detect "small" fractions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to allow for a certain error and not all fractions can be exactly represented as scalar values.

```
public static String toFraction(double d, double err) {
    String s = Long.toString((long) d);
    d -= (long) d;
    if (d > err) {
        for (int den = 2, max = (int) (1 / err); den < max; den++) {
            long num = Math.round(d * den);
            double d2 = (double) num / den;
            if (Math.abs(d - d2) <= err)
                return (s.equals("0") ? "" : s + " ") + num +"/"+den;
        }
    }
    return s;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(toFraction(1.0/3, 1e-6));
    System.out.println(toFraction(1.23456789, 1e-6));
    System.out.println(toFraction(Math.E, 1e-6));
    System.out.println(toFraction(Math.PI, 1e-6));
    for (double d = 10; d < 1e15; d *= 10)
        System.out.println(toFraction(Math.PI, 1.0 / d));
}
```

prints

```
1/3
1 19/81
2 719/1001
3 16/113
3 1/5
3 1/7
3 9/64
3 15/106
3 16/113
3 16/113
3 3423/24175
3 4543/32085
3 4687/33102
3 14093/99532
3 37576/265381
3 192583/1360120
3 244252/1725033
3 2635103/18610450
```

Note: this finds the 21/7, 333/106 and 355/113 approximations for PI.

Comment: The problem seems highly related to printing floating points out. I wonder if you can use the same grisu3 strategy that finds the smallest printable string that will return the binary representation of the float. The problem is a little different though: find the fraction with the smallest denominator that when converting to floating point will return the floating point number. Grisu3 needs to fall back to bignum arithmetic to do this though in small number of cases.

Answer (score 3):

No `double` value is equal to one third, so the only way your program can be made to print `1/3` is if you change the specification of the method to favour "nice" answers rather than the answer that is technically correct.

One thing you could do is choose a maximum denominator for the answers, say 100, and return the closest fraction with denominator 100 or less.

Here is how you could implement this using Java 8 streams:

```
public static String toFraction(double val) {
    int b = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
                     .boxed()
                     .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(n -> Math.abs(val * n - Math.round(val * n))))
                     .get();
    int a = (int) Math.round(val * b);
    int h = gcm(a, b);
    return a/h + "/" + b/h;
}
```

There is no nice approach to this. `double` is not very good for this sort of thing. Note that `BigDecimal` can't represent 1/3 either, so you'll have the same problem with that class.

Answer (score 0):

There are nice ways to handle this but you will need to look at special cases. For example, if the numerator is 1 then the fraction is already reduced and you simply strip out the decimal places and return what you were given.